# Which mailserver with web interface for Ubuntu + Nginx + Passenger + Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, ubuntu-10.04, mail-server

I'm running a virtual server with Ubuntu 10.04, Nginx, Phusion Passenger and Ruby on Rails 3. And sending mails via my rails app is no problem, as rails makes it preatty is. But I also want to send and receive mails via a mail client like Outlook, Mail or Thunderbird and I want to a way to manage the mail accounts via a web interface.

The most things I found are either too powerful and too pricy (like cPanel with Nginx Support) or they are impossible for me to setup. So, long story short:

I'm searching for a Mailserver which runs on Ubuntu 10.04, Nginx and Passenger, that supports at least POP (but IMAP would also be great) and which has a web interface for managing which is either easy to setup or, even better, written in ruby.

As long as the documentation is good and it runs I'm happy. Any recommendation or personal experience would be helpful.

Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who is interested, I used the following combination:

Postfix + Courier as Mailserver and Postfixadmin as Administrationtool

And I tried to install Roundcube and Postatmail, but they both failed. Roundcube didn't work at all and Postatmail had some crazy errors with Suhosin. So I'm dismissing the webmail interface.